# how to convert this script to run multiple bots

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a scripts which responsible for forwarding messages from one channel to other channels.
Scripts looks something like below:
How can I achieve to run different client on every channel.
I am using Telethon.

```
client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[channel_id]))
async def handler(event):
    channels = get_channels()
    replacements = get_replacements()
    msg_first = copy.copy(event.message.text)
    for channel in channels:
        replacements_api = get_replacement(channel['channel_id'], replacements)
        for rep_api in replacements_api:
            # do some stuff here

        await client.send_message(channel['channel_id'], message=event.message)
       
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: To be more specific, i want to get bots' token from database or external api, and use them dynamically in scripts. Let's say that i am able to get it from get_channels() method.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that by just calling the `run_until_disconnected()` of one client:

```py
client0 = ...
client1 = ...
client2 = ...
client0.start()
client1.start()
client2.start()

...
...
...

client2.run_until_disconnected()
```